# Custom environment variable is not read from NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I started learning NodeJS and I encounter an issue when I define an environment variable and then I try to read it from inside the code, but the value is always empty.

I am using the `config` module, so I have two files defined: `default.json`:

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": ""
}
```

And `custom-environment-variables.json`:

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": "app_jwtPrivateKey"
}
```

And I read this from `index.js` file:

```
if(!config.get('jwtPrivateKey')) {
    console.error('FATAL ERROR: jwtPrivateKey not defined');
    process.exit(1);
}
```

And from terminal I do this:

```
export app_jwtPrivateKey=mySecureKey
```

But I always get the error that this is not defined.

I searched other questions and everybody recommends using different module than `config` like `env`, but I am curious to know what the solution is using `config`.

Comment: works for me. Did you put the `custom-environment-variables.json` in the `config/` folder?

Comment: @Ente: yes, both json files are in the .config folder. Very strange that it doesn't work for me. For me it reads the value from default.json file, not the other file...

Comment: which version of `config` do you have installed? 
Custom Environment Variables were introduced with 1.1.0.

Comment: 3.2.3, I just install it today

Comment: how do you export and run the app?

Comment: Hmm, I just installed config again....and started working now ! Very strange, I run with node index.js, but only now it started working

Comment: I am guessing that your environment variable wasn't exported when you ran node, maybe?..

Comment: No idea to be sure, but glad its working now.

Comment: I didn't even notice, the problem appears only when running from Visual Studio Code terminal. If I run from mac os terminal it works.

Answer (score 0):

create folder named `config` and place the `default.json` file inside it 
config expected path from the app root is `config/default.json`.
NOTE : it's `config` not `.config`

Comment: I already have this setup. Still doesn't work. It reads the value from default.json not custom-environment-variables.json.